# Insert de uma select em c#

Tags: c#, select, sql-insert

Boa Noite!
Pessoal,
Eu tenho uma select funcionando normalmente e exibindo o resultado em um datagridviewer tudo certinho, porém, eu preciso pegar o resultado desta consulta que é feita no banco de dados mysql do servidor X e gravar em uma tabela idêntica no banco de dados do servidor Y, como faço o insert de uma select no c#?

Segue abaixo minha query.

```
try
{
    conexao = new MySqlConnection("server=xxxxx;database=xxxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxxx;port=3306;SSL Mode = none");

    DateTime DataFechInicio = dtpFechInicio.Value;
    DateTime DataFechFim = dtpFechFim.Value;

    strSQL = "SELECT " +
                     "p.Nome," +
                     "v.Vencimento," +
                     "Concat('R$ ',Format(v.Valor,2,'de_DE')) as Valor," +
                     "bd.Descricao as 'Centro de Custo'" +
             "FROM pessoa p " +
                            "INNER JOIN pedido pd " +
                                                  "ON p.idpessoa = pd.fornecedor " +
                            "INNER JOIN pedvenc v " +
                                                  "ON v.idpedido = pd.idpedido " +
                            "INNER JOIN base_dpto bd " +
                                                     "ON bd.CCUSTO = v.CCUSTO " +
             "WHERE v.vencimento " +
                       "BETWEEN '" + DataFechInicio.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' " +
                               "AND '" + DataFechFim.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' " +
                               "AND pd.cnsstatus = 'FECHADO' " +
                               "AND pd.cnscanmom IS NULL " +
              "ORDER  BY nome ASC";

    da = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, conexao);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);

    dgvFechDados.DataSource = dt;

    conexao.Open(); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
finally
{
    conexao.Close();
    conexao = null;
}
```

Comment: não é mais fácil fazer isso no servidor mesmo? pode ser algo assim `insert into serverY.database.tabela(campos...) select campos from serverX.database.tabela`

Answer (score 0):

Amigo vc ira precisar montar a query de insert e fazer rodar no banco alvo, do mesmo jeito que vc faz o select, porem montando a string e concatenando o valor que vc adquiriu no select.

Por exemplo vc fez o select que rertonou o seguinte array de objetos
[{nome:joao, idade:20}, {nome:joaquina, idade:19}, {nome:fulano, idade 30}]

com esse array vc ira montar sua query dinamicamente percorrendo os valores e concatenando, depois é só executar a query assim como a query do select